# Blinking Cursor after Switching on

Tags: 14.04, boot, cursor

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series laptop pre-installed with Ubuntu 14.04 for around 4 months now. Before that I had 12.04. It has never given me an issue but a couple of hours ago, I switched off my laptop and switched it on back again to be greeted with a blinking cursor.

I have tried:

- Searching AskUbuntu but almost everyone can access GRUB or has a Live CD.
- Using the Right Shift key when it boots. No GRUB.
- <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> to run the diagnostic tests and it was all fine. There are no problems. I have never used or installed Windows with 
  Ubuntu and I dont have a USB key/CD from which I can reinstall Ubuntu.
- So I did something called as Legacy option and changed it from "Legacy" to "UEFI".

I went to Dell Recovery mode and it gave me an error on a purple screen.

Error: plymouthd: ply-text-display.c:243: ply_text_display_write: Assertion `format != ((void *)0)' failed. (empty title field in text plugin theme)

A few seconds later, lines stating "line 7: cant open /dev/sr0: No medium found".

"unable to find a medium containing a live file system".

until now I have not seen the ubuntu screen with the dots.

What do I do? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Plug the HDD into another Linux box and see if you can access your main EXT4 partition.